# Android app that lets me set daily tasks with alarms and offset the time of a group of tasks

Tags: android, calendar, reminders

I need an Android app which will allow me to set a bunch of daily tasks with alarms, and then offset the times of a group of tasks.

For example, if I have 10 things to do every morning and I have an alarm set for each in sequence (7am, 7.20am, 8am etc.), I need to be able to move all of these times in case I need to wake up later or anything unexpected gets in the way (e.g. move all tasks forward an hour, so 8am, 8.20am, 9am etc.).

The application would ideally be free but I am willing to pay a small amount.